# Top Users page does not render well when there is nothing to report in the last 30 days

Tags: bug, status-completed, design, top-users

When viewing a [top users page that has no activity in the last 30 days](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/tags/bunnies/topusers), the columns do not render well:

[image: pull bunnies, pull!]

No matter how hard these bunnies try, they can't separate the columns properly.

Comment: Hmmm... I'm torn: This question just begs to be tagged [bunnies]; doing so, however, would [literally](http://xkcd.org/725/) render this bug fixed.

Comment: My question for you is, why were you looking up statistics for the `bunnies` tag?

Comment: Dawwwwwwwwwwwwwwwww look at the little bunnies!

Comment: Hey, Ether.... BC rules :D

Comment: @Carson: yes, yes it does. :)

Comment: @balpha: Only someone answers it, I believe.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Is it looking good enough now to close this?

Comment: I'd say yes.  Good work.

Comment: Well, look at the [C#](http://stackoverflow.com/tags/c%23/stats "The MOST POPULAR tag!!!!") tag though.  Skeet's badge counts on the left overlap the right column.  I think that the current solution is better than what was implemented before.  But that bug should be pointed out.

Comment: @jjnguy Jon Skeet violates the rules of CSS

Comment: so you are saying `Jon Skeet == IE`